# Active record group_by with each loop rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, group-by

I am applying group by on active records and then do each to access the records from hash.

Following is my code

```
invoice_transactions.group_by(&:paymentable_id).each do |invoice_id, transactions|
  invoice = Invoice.find invoice_id
  transaction_details = get_transactions(transactions, timezone)
  invoice_details.push({
    customer_name: invoice&.customer&.fully_qualified_name&.strip})
```

Here I need to find the invoice by invoice_id in a separate line.

```
invoice = Invoice.find invoice_id
```

My question is how can I find invoice in the same line as a group by instead of getting invoice_id to get invoice object and no need for find in second line?

something like

```
invoice_transactions.group{|paymentable_id| Invoice.find paymentable_id}.each do |invoice, transactions|
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry! You have to do like this.

Comment: No I got it we can do it by invoice_transactions.group_by{[i] Invoice.find i.paymentable_id}.each do | invoice_id, transactions|

Comment: Eventually you are doing the same thing. It's better to do in current way.

Comment: If you have a `paymentable` association between `InvoiceTransaction` and `Invoice`, you could do it like `invoice_transactions.group_by(&:paymentable)` which would use the `paymentable` object itself as the hash key